# Adding acronym with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTMl field that has this markup:

```
<label for="id_data_path_ip_0">
<input class="radiolist inline" id="id_data_path_ip_0" name="data_path_ip" type="radio" value="Tool"> Same as Tool</label>
```

Is there a way to add an acronym to this with jQuery? If I was writing the HTML it would look like this:

```
<label for="id_data_path_ip_0">
<acronym class="help" title="This requires the setup of a remote mount.">?</acronym>
<input class="radiolist inline" id="id_data_path_ip_0" name="data_path_ip" type="radio" value="Tool"> Same as Tool</label>
```

Comment: `<acronym>` has actually been deprecated in HTML5 in favor of `<abbr>`. The distinction between abbreviation and acronym is no longer made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it after the `label` then you need to target the `label` for the `.after()` code..

```
var abbr = '<abbr class="help" title="This requires the setup of a remote mount.">?</abbr>'
$('label[for="id_data_path_ip_0"]').after(abbr);
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/hfEJ2/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are after but you could use `.before()` to insert the acronym before the input tag:

```
$(".radiolist").before( "<acornym....." );
```

http://api.jquery.com/before/

Comment: Thanks for the replies, but I mistyped what I wanted. I really want it to be like this:

<label for="id_data_path_ip_0">
<input class="radiolist inline" id="id_data_path_ip_0" name="data_path_ip" type="radio" value="Tool"> Same as Tool</label>
<acronym class="help" title="This requires the setup of a remote mount.">?</acronym>

With the ? after the 'Same as Tool" 

If I do this:

            $('#id_data_path_ip_o')
                .after('<acronym class="help" title="This requires the setup of a remote mount.">?</acronym>');

it comes out between the radio button and the text.