# jQuery: Automatically add abbr tags to defined acronyms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, usability

**The issue**

I'd like to improve the usability of a website by adding abbreviation tags to selected acronyms, so people are able to follow a given text even without knowing all the cool terms and definitions other people use in the day-to-day business of their domain.

In the past, I added these tags manually, so `CMS` became `<abbr title="Content Management System">CMS</abbr>` and so on. To be honest: This approach sucks and is hard to keep to.

**The idea**

Use jQuery (or JavaScript) – maybe in combination with JSON – to match any text between the `<main>` tags against a list of acronyms, and whenever an element is found it is automatically wrapped with `abbr` tags.

**The solution?**

Up to now, I only have a concept because all related approaches I found seem to target either a given string or a tag ([example with acronym](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21468089/adding-acronym-with-jquery)). So what would you recommend to solve this issue? In short:

1. Get the content between `<main>` tags
2. Match the content against a list of acronyms
3. Wrap acronyms with `<abbr>` tags to provide the corresponding information

**As a side note**

I found an age-old stackoverflow post recommending to solve such an issue server-side. Though I also think that's not the worst idea, I'd like to emphasize that I need a solution which works with static pages, too. So, I'd highly appreciate if you could refrain from fights over the question what's better: server-side vs client-side?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works pretty well but has some shortcomings. For the matter of documentation, I add the original answer by myself and add my observations.

### Original reply

There's a way to achieve your goal, but searching your entire text for known acronyms may be costy (from performance standpoint) if there's a large number of those, gathered from across different domains (with low probability for each to be found within your text).

However, you may consider following approach:

- have your know acronyms and their definitions within an object (e.g. `{acronym: 'CMS', meaning: 'Content Management System'}`)
- traverse your text contents for a matching acronym and replace with corresponding `<abbr>` element

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  let abbreviations = [
          {abbreviation: 'CMS', meaning: 'Content Management System'},
          {abbreviation: 'ECM', meaning: 'Enterprise Content Management'},
          {abbreviation: 'WCM', meaning: 'Web Content Management'}
        ],
        mainHtml = $('main').html()
  
  mainHtml = mainHtml.replace(
    new RegExp(abbreviations.map(({abbreviation}) => abbreviation).join('|'), 'g'),
    m => {
      const matchingAbbreviation = abbreviations.find(({abbreviation}) => abbreviation == m),
            {abbreviation:content, meaning:title} = matchingAbbreviation
      return `<abbr title="${title}">${content}</abbr>`
    }
  )
  
  $('main').html(mainHtml)
})
```

```css
abbr { /* For demo purpose */
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #284b63;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>CMS is a software application that can be used to manage the creation and modification of digital content. CMSs are typically used for ECM and WCM. ECM typically supports multiple users in a collaborative environment by integrating document management, digital asset management and record retention. Alternatively, WCM is the collaborative authoring for websites and may include text and embed graphics, photos, video, audio, maps and program code that display content and interact with the user. ECM typically includes a WCM function</main>
```

Above will work pretty fast when there's a moderately large list of acronyms.

If your list happens to be way too large and text to modify is much smaller, it could make sense going the other way around: loop through array of abbreviations and do find-replace within target text:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {

  let abbreviations = [{
        abbreviation: 'CMS',
        meaning: 'Content Management System'
      },
      {
        abbreviation: 'ECM',
        meaning: 'Enterprise Content Management'
      },
      {
        abbreviation: 'WCM',
        meaning: 'Web Content Management'
      }
    ],
    mainHtml = $('main').html()

  abbreviations.forEach(({
    abbreviation: content,
    meaning: title
  }) => {
    mainHtml = mainHtml.replace(new RegExp(content, 'g'), `<abbr title="${title}">${content}</abbr>`)
  })

  $('main').html(mainHtml)
})
```

```css
abbr {
  /* For demo purpose */
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #284b63;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>CMS is a software application that can be used to manage the creation and modification of digital content. CMSs are typically used for ECM and WCM. ECM typically supports multiple users in a collaborative environment by integrating document management,
  digital asset management and record retention. Alternatively, WCM is the collaborative authoring for websites and may include text and embed graphics, photos, video, audio, maps and program code that display content and interact with the user. ECM typically
  includes a WCM function</main>
```

### My observations

**No. 1**

The code works pretty well in both directions. The only shortcoming is that it does not only target the text itself but, e.g., tags like the achor tag; i.e. if I have a link with the data-target value of `#collapseCMS`, the `<abbr>` tag will be applied to this string too with the unwanted side effect of destroying the link.

**No. 2**

Even if I make sure that no string in a tag is targeted, the code somehow "destroys" the collapsing effect which I built in by the use of Bootstrap 4.

```
$('#team .collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $('.collapse.show').each(function() {
    $(this).collapse('hide');
  })
})
```

With this code, I want to ensure that an opened section will be closed when another section is opened. If I apply the code for the acronyms, all sections can be opened independently.

**No. 3**

If you use the popper.js to style your tooltips, make sure to initialize it after the above-mentioned code. Otherwise, the style will not be applied and you get the "classic tooltips".